# Angular Routing not working except for empty name

Tags: angular, angular-routing, router-outlet

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from "@angular/router";
import {NotfoundComponent} from "../shared/components/notfound/notfound.component";
import {IssuesComponent} from "../business/pages/issues/issues.component";
import {AddToInventoryComponent} from "../business/pages/add-to-inventory/add-to-inventory.component";
import {BoxTransferComponent} from "../business/pages/box-transfer/box-transfer.component";

const routes : Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: IssuesComponent,
        data: {title: 'App - Issues'}
    },
    {
        path: 'add',
        component: AddToInventoryComponent,
        data: {title: 'App - Add To Inventory'}
    },
    {
        path: 'boxtransfer',
        component: BoxTransferComponent,
        data: {title: 'App - Transfer Inventory'}
    },
    {
        path: 'notfound',
        component: NotfoundComponent,
        data: {title: 'App - Page Not Found'}
    },
]


@NgModule({
    declarations: [],
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRouteModule {
}
```

The only route that is loading is where **path: ''**

If I manually type localhost:4200/add it will redirect to localhost:4200
If I try to load any route, it will redirect to localhost:4200

What am I doing wrong here?

Okay new information

If I link pages in the HTML to

```
<a routerLink="/add"
```

The link loads localhost:4200/add

However if I manually type it then it redirects me to /

Comment: Are you using `ng s[erve]` or how are you hosting the app?

Comment: ng serve is how I am testing it. I am using macOS

Comment: Yeah, you're right, they look fine. I can't spot a mistake in your module itself. I might admit that it has been quite some time that I worked with Angular. Does the route work if you navigate to it from Typescript? If so,  maybe `useHash` set to `true` on the import of the RouterModule _might_ help (just as a purpose to debug the router!)

Comment: If I add an html link like 
<a routerLink="/add" 
it works

if I type /add to the url, it redirects to /

Comment: Yeah, I believe this is related to the section [Routed apps must fall back to index.html](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fall-back-to-indexhtml) - but I don't remember how the internals of ng s were in that regard. As I said, you might try out using hashed URLs instead. Another option would be just to not access the routes directly with ng s and rely on the deployment server to handle it correctly.

Comment: What is the value of the attribute href of <base> in your index.html ? It should be '/' or './'.